# cts:value-co-occurrences returning empty sequence

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to find co-occurrences of all documents which have a property `<id>` in the document-properties.. Following is the code I am doing to list the co-occurrences and is not working.. can someone suggest what I am doing wrong.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace prop = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";


 cts:value-co-occurrences(
              cts:element-reference(xs:QName('prop:id')),
              cts:uri-reference())
```

I did create the element range index on this property
[image]

Comment: Was there an error message?

Comment: Please post a sample properties fragment so that we can verify that the element in question is actually in the properties namespace.

Comment: Just tried this with some data I had handy -- I got no results until I fixed a namespace problem, then I got results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: I have edited this answer after acceptance because I gave three items to look at. The edit is to highlight the part of the answer that gave the solution

---

**Solution: - Namespace in properties fragment was different**

- This is sometimes confusing for people.
- There is an XML document in the property fragment - always.
- The node itself declares a namespace, but it is prefixed as 'prop'.
- However, the properties you add (XML elements) are not under the above namespace - unless of course you actually use the prop prefix yourself.
- End result for this challenge was that the user created an index on an element in the properties fragment and scoped the index to the properties namespace. This created a totally valid index - just empty because no elements matched.

Original wording of response:

Are you sure the element in question is actually in the properties namespace as your index shows? A quick dump of cts:element-values may show this. I mention this because adding properties to the properties fragment does not infer that they are in the properties namespace.

### --

---

Other ideas - not the answer, but path of investigation

I think you are looking for [cts:value-tuples](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-tuples) and not co-occurance based on your example.

---

However: from your problem statement, why do you not just use [cts:uris()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris) constrained by an [cts:element-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query) on the property fragment (and all without a range index)

This can tell you all URIs where element my-element exists in the properties fragment:

```
cts:uris("", (),
  cts:properties-fragment-query(
    cts:element-query(xs:QName("my-element"),
      cts:and-query( () )) 
    )
)
```

Comment: I tried this `cts:value-tuples(
              (cts:element-reference(xs:QName('prop:id')),
              cts:uri-reference()),('properties'))` .. I still get `your query returned an empty sequence`

Comment: The reason I want co-occurrences is that there might be documents with the same id, so I only want one document-uri for a given search criteria.. I have documents and each document have artifact documents that have same `<id>` property and I want to get only one document for a given `<id>` for a given search criteria

Comment: I think the only real difference between cts:value-co-occurrences() and cts:value-tuples is that the latter allows you to specify more than two index references.

Comment: Yup My bad it was a namespace issue, when setting the properties I did not set the namespace for my properties..

Comment: Nice!  glad it worked.  I'll adjust the answer so it is clear which item was the culprit - but Ill leave the others as reference.

Answer (score 1):

No error message provided, so this is a guess. Make sure you have the URI lexicon turned on -- cts:uri-reference will throw an error otherwise.

Comment: Hmm.. I do not get any error.. just says `your query returned an empty sequence` ..But when I do the same, but instead of document-properties I do an xml tag inside the documents which have element-range index it works..